# Using geometry to find all possible values of the determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix whose entries are $0$ or $1$

Tags: geometry, determinant

> The matrix $A_{3\times 3}$ has all its entries $0$ or $1$. All possible values of $\det A$ are ...

From trial method, I know the answer to be $\pm2$, $\pm 1$, $0$. For a more complicated matrix the trial would be tedious, so I was looking for a geometric method.

I know the columns are vectors and the determinant is the volume of the parallelepiped formed. Can anyone help me with this thinking process? I can tell $0$, $\pm1$ as values easily, but how to think for greater values for other such determinant (limit to $3\times 3$)?

Comment: In the plane the "volume" is just the area. Start with a square, then ask how you get from that area to the volume of a cube with faces the size of that square. See if you can generalize from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to a sign, the determinant is the volume of a parallelepiped with sides
$\in \{ 0, 1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3} \}$.

Since the volume is an integer, if none of the sides is $\sqrt{3}$, the volume is at most $\lfloor \sqrt{2}^3 \rfloor = 2$. In fact, the volume $2$ is realizable. e.g. following matrix has determinant $2$ ${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$.
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

If the parallelepiped has a side $\sqrt{3}$. One of the column is all $1$.
If you project the parallelepiped to a plane perpendicular to the $(1,1,1)$ direction. You obtain a parallelogram. If the parallelogram non-degenerate,
it has sides $\sqrt{\frac23}$. In this case, the volume of the
parallelepiped is at most $\left\lfloor \sqrt{3} \sqrt{\frac23}^2\right\rfloor = 1$

Combine these, we find the possible values of the determinant is $0$, $\pm 1$ and $\pm 2$.

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - In order for the determinant equals to $\pm 2$, up to permutation of rows/columns, this is the only choice. When the volume is $2$, all sides of the parallelepiped need to be $\sqrt{2}$. Configuration of sides like $( \sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}, 1 )$ won't work because the two longer sides are not perpendicular to each other.

Comment: You obtain a parallelogram. If the parallelogram non-degenerate, it has sides 23−−√. In this case, the volume of the parallelepiped is at most ⌊3–√23−−√2⌋=1. Can you explain this part a little bit? Thanks..

Comment: @Guji2203 Pick a physical cube of side $1$, look at it along direction of a diagonal $d$, you will see a regular hexagon of side $\sqrt{\frac23}$. If parallelepiped  $P$ is non-degenrate and one of its side is parallel to $d$, other two sides of $P$ will get projected to segments joining the center and vertices of the hexagon. The projection of $P$ onto a plane perpendicular to $d$ will be a parallelogram (let's call that $Q$). To compute volume of $P$, slide points inside $P$ along directions of $d$ until you get a cylinder with height $\sqrt{3}$, base $Q$ and has same volume as $P$.

Comment: Thanks i understood.